# Docxtemplater (browser) strings and numbers in conditions not working

Tags: docxtemplater

https://docxtemplater.com/docs/installation/#browser-js-files

Hi, I am working on the latest release (also tried with 3.31.2 and 3.9.9 but when I define the following variables:

```js
// Render the document (Replace {first_name} by John, {last_name} by Doe, ...)
doc.render({
    test : "yes",
});
```

and I have the following Word template:

```
{#test == "yes"}
They are many users.
{/test == "yes"}
```

It doesn't work : the content inside the condition is not rendered.

Already tried to:

- replace the test string with numbers, not working;
- use any type of double and single quote in Word, not working.

Only conditions like {#ifUser} with `{ifUser: true}` work.

Answer (score 0):

Docxtemplater has support for conditions, and it has to be enabled (it is not by default).

## Update on September 2023

You can render conditions such as `{#test == "yes"}` by doing the following :

First install the angular-expressions library :

```bash
npm install --save angular-expressions
```

then in your code, simply write :

```js
const expressionParser = require("docxtemplater/expressions.js");
new Docxtemplater(zip, { parser: expressionParser });
```

This version has the same feature set as the outdated solution below, is simpler to maintain for you (no code), and also faster
(the outdated version had a performance issue with big loops and big JSON
objects).

### Note that is also possible to add some "filters", like this :

```js
expressionParser.filters.lower = function (input) {
    // This condition should be used to make sure that if your input is
    // undefined, your output will be undefined as well and will not
    // throw an error
    if (!input) return input;
    return input.toLowerCase();
};
```

Which will allow you to write `{client.name | lower}` in your template to make a string lowercase.

## Outdated answer (for version 3.31.6 and before)

The simplest setup would be to first install angular-expressions and lodash :

```bash
npm install --save angular-expressions lodash
```

Then use following code sample :

```js
var expressions = require("angular-expressions");
var assign = require("lodash/assign");
// define your filter functions here, for example
// to be able to write {clientname | lower}

function angularParser(tag) {
    tag = tag
        .replace(/^\.$/, "this")
        .replace(/(’|‘)/g, "'")
        .replace(/(“|”)/g, '"');
    const expr = expressions.compile(tag);
    return {
        get: function (scope, context) {
            let obj = {};
            const scopeList = context.scopeList;
            const num = context.num;
            for (let i = 0, len = num + 1; i < len; i++) {
                obj = assign(obj, scopeList[i]);
            }
            return expr(scope, obj);
        },
    };
}
new Docxtemplater(zip, { parser: angularParser });
```

See the following doc :

https://docxtemplater.com/docs/angular-parse/